# Determining the number of ways to color the faces of a triangular prism with 4 colours using the counting theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups

Consider the symmetry group of rotations in $3$ dimensions of the triangular prism, acting on colourings of the faces of a triangular prism with $4$ colours (red, blue, yellow and green).  Note that the triangular faces are equilateral triangles. 
[triangular prism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl8qP.png)

Use the counting theorem to determine the number of colourings of the faces of the prism with $4$ colours, where two colourings are considered the same if one can be obtained from the other by applying an element from the symmetry group of rotations of the prism.

For the counting theorem I know that the size of my $|G| = 12$ since there are $12$ symmetries for my triangular prism and the fix (Identity) will be $3^4$. I'm having trouble finding out what my other fix functions should be.

Comment: How do you define the triangular prism? I just googled it (I am not native), and it seems to have only three orientation preserving symmetries (you wrote rotations).

Comment: Is your prism really a [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron)? (That would make it $12$ symmetries rather than the $6$ you have for what is conventionally called a [triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism).) And by "the counting theorem", do you mean [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)?